# Why is sometimes "he were" used (instead of "he was")?

Tags: tense, past-tense, subjunctives

In school we learned that the past tense of "to be" for "he" is "was". But now I stumbled upon the following phrase on the internet:

> He wishes he were born rich.

Why is "were" instead of "was" used here? What is the exact rule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it "If I were you" and not "If I was you"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/why-is-it-if-i-were-you-and-not-if-i-was-you) Also more specifically, ["I wish I was" vs. "I wish I were"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244909/i-wish-i-was-vs-i-wish-i-were), but all the answers to that one are in comments, so I can't cite it as the primary duplicate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, thank you! :)

Comment: Ah - so you didn't need that second link anyway! :)

Comment: This "were" is not a tense form, but a mood form, sometimes called 'irrealis', indicating that it conveys varying degrees of remoteness from factuality.  The irrealis mood form "were" is unique to _be_, and limited to the 1st and 3rd person singular. It's an untidy relic of an earlier system, and some speakers usually, if not always, use preterite "was" instead.