# Does "is" turn into "was" or "were" in indirect speech?

Tags: conditional-constructions, reported-speech

Not sure if "is" becomes  "was" or "were" when passing from direct speech conditional to indirect speech.

Direct speech:

> The plane can make tight turns if the wind is weak.

Indirect speech:

> He told me that the plane, which crashed, could make tight turns if the wind was (or were?) weak.

Comment: The verb tense should relate to its subject,  either "...if the wind was weak," or "...if the winds were weak." 

However, that being said there is still some wobbliness about this because of "mood".  This is out of my comfort zone so I'm going to refer you here:  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/why-is-it-if-i-were-you-and-not-if-i-was-you

Answer (score 11):

It is not the change to indirect speech which dictates the change in verb form; rather it is the use of the verb *could* to describe the possibility of an outcome contrary to what occurred, and the introduction of information about that outcome in the form of the parenthetical *which crashed.*

> He told me that the plane, which crashed, could make tight turns if the wind **were** weak.

This is the subjunctive mood; it is revealed when we use a conditional like *could* to introduce a speculative event which is contrary to fact. That the plane crashed provides a hint that the wind was *not* weak.

Comment: Correct - worth clearly pointing out that this has nothing to do with the "indirect speech" (a phrase which the OP appears to use in order to denote the second-hand accounting?)

Comment: Was just having a go at that... (_indirect speech_ or _reported speech_ is what I'd call it, certainly. See [this](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/direct-and-indirect-speech/) e.g.)

Comment: Spot on now. :)

Comment: The more I look at this, the more important is the parenthetical. Without it, the sentence is nothing more than reported speech causing the backshift _can⇒could._ With it, _could_ is a true conditional. I think. I'm upvoting the question in the hope of attracting a more certain analysis.

Comment: The use of the subjunctive mood is reducing in modern English. In the 19th century you would have said "The ship can make tight turns if the wind *be* weak." (replacing "plane" by "ship" for the obvious reason!) using the subjunctive mood "be", but modern English would always use "is". See for example https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UpcNAQAAIAAJ&pg=PR44&lpg=PR44&dq=%22if+the+wind+be+strong%22&source=bl&ots=q5ovXjVt1M&sig=wREGcumyBnwN5rPTPzWHW2bFvf4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjumeSEu7DPAhVWFMAKHSJJCM4Q6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%22if%20the%20wind%20be%20strong%22&f=false (published in 1840)

Comment: "If the winds were weak, the plane could make tight turns" is the "normal" ordering of the counterfactual conditional. But that is also a statement about a present counterfactual statement (i.e. implies currently the winds are not weak). But I don't know of any crashed plane that can make any turn in any wind. If the plane hadn't crashed, then if the wind were weak, the plane could make tight turns...

Comment: @alephzero Absolutely. In fact, Murphy's EGIU dispenses with it almost entirely. I left such notes out of the answer here because that's a whole nother question...(insert emoticon)

Comment: I think you and @eques are  confusing the issue. *Eg*, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "was" vs. "were" is simply singular vs. plural, and based on the subject they are enacted by.

`if the wind was weak.` : "wind" is singular => "was".

`if the winds were weak.` : "winds" is plural => "were".

As a side note, both "the wind was" and "the winds were" are idiomatically the same.

Comment: although note that in this case we have a condition which could be counterfactual (i.e. specifying that the wind was in fact not weak) thus "if the wind were weak" could also be seen

Comment: @eques So: the parenthetical, which provides information about the past event, changes this from a simple backshift resulting from reported speech into a usage of _could_ as true conditional, revealing the subjunctive. What say you aye or nay?

Comment: could as conditional with subjunctive actually is odd here since the plane is described as "crashed" (i.e. in the past). A counterfactual in the past would ordinarily use perfects ("If the wind had been light"). I couldn't find much info on back-shifting conditional statements (as in reported speech)

Answer (score 0):

You ask about turning the following conditional into reported speech:

> The plane can make tight turns if the wind is weak.

The use of present tenses marks this as a real  conditional. In other words, this is talking about something that is in the realm of the real, *grammatically speaking*<sup>1</sup>.  We   are not talking about unreality or *irrealis* here. Note that the modal *can* here refers to ability. You can  also *is able to*.

If you want to maintain this type of conditional in reported speech, you change the present tense to past tense, resulting in

> He told me that the plane could make tight turns if the wind was  weak.

Note that *could* here retains the sense of ability. You could also write *was able to*.

Introducing the additional information that the plane  crashed does not change the type of  conditional sentence that you have, so the verb tenses are the same as without this clause:

> He told me that the plane, which crashed, could make tight turns if the wind was weak.

It's interesting that the plane  crashed, but this fact changes nothing about the type of conditional sentence you have. You  could just as well have  introduced the fact that the plane landed safely.

Additional information:

*Were* is the past tense of *are*, not *is*.

Both *were* and *was* are also used in unreal conditionals,  but  your sentence is not an unreal conditional.

---

<sup>1</sup> Whether  planes in general  or this specific plane  can actually make tight turns in weak wind has nothing to do with the *grammar* of the sentence; nor does it matter if the speaker is  wrong  or even lying about the plane: grammatically this is a real conditional. For the forms of conditional sentences, see, for example, [mindmeister](https://www.mindmeister.com/70313946/conditionals-real-vs-hypothetical-conditions-4a).