# Word usage. Grammaticality

Tags: word-usage, usage

The villagers advised him to run uphill if he 'were' / was ever unfortunate enough to be chased by a bear.
Which out of the two is correct? Was or were? 
The word 'if' makes the sentence a conditional clause ... but some people say that 'was' is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If something was vs If something were.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110497/if-something-was-vs-if-something-were) That question is closer to the *exact* construction here, but [Why is it “If I were you” and not “If I was you”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/) is a better question with better answers.

Answer (score -1):

If I **were** ever unfortunate enough to be chased by a bear, I would explain to it that it was an impossible occurrence, so get lost, buddy!

If I **was** ever unfortunate enough to be chased by a bear, I would run like hell because it was a quite probable thing to be chased and eaten by a bear.

Comment: A singular, uncountable noun in English must be preceded by a determiner.

Comment: That means, if the occurrence of something is possible , then we should use 'was' and if it isn' , then the word 'were' is correct. Am I right? If not, please help again!

Comment: @ P. E. Dant    Sorry, there are no articles in Russian ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ Ayesha  Apparently so, but I'm not a native speaker.