# If it were "to" me OR If it were "for" me?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

To say that if something were in my hands to or in my capability (but it's actually isn't), which is correct:
If it were **"to"** me, I would do so and so
OR
If it were **"for"** me, I would do so and so
Thanks

Comment: Isnt it just "if it were me"?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I meant. Example to clarify:
If it were to me, I wouldn't let you go. (but I am unable to do so).

Comment: or do you mean "if it weren't for me"

Comment: I mean to say: If it were (in my hands, in my capability), then I would do so. It is a hypothetical situation, not in the past, but in the present.

Comment: Neither. It's *...if it were **up to** me [I'd do blah blah]*

Comment: "If it were to me" is grammatically wrong ^ Read FumbleFinger's comment

Comment: Note that *if it were up to me* means *if I was the person **responsible for deciding** what to do*. It *doesn't* exactly mean *if I was **capable** of doing it*.

Comment: Ok. Thank you both.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it ok if i copy your comment and credit you in my answer? Laith i tried to answer your question below :)

Comment: It may be interesting to compare ***Is it up to you**?* (Are you the person *responsible* for doing it?) with ***Are you up to it**?* (Are you *capable* of doing it?). Also *Are you up **for** it?* (informal; Are you *willing* to do it?).

Comment: @DialFrost: Please do. Always!

Comment: @LaithLeo: Note that *in principle* a hypothetical situation in the *past* should be referenced using Past *Perfect* (because the state of being responsible must inevitably have "occurred / applied" *before* that decision, regardless of who actually *made* the decision). So *If it **had been** up to me, I would have done it differently*. But in practice many native speakers don't always bother with the Perfect for the initial verb: *If it **was** up to me, I'd have done something else.* That's especially the case if whatever causes it *not* to be up to me is still true and/or "timeless".

Comment: Hi! Please edit the question itself to include the explanation that you put in a comment. Comments aren't an official part of the question and can sometimes be deleted; right now, the question isn't officially clear enough to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

As what @FumbleFingers has said, the supposed answer is:

> If it were **up to** me, I would do something

However, this is only if I was the person responsible for deciding what to do. It doesn't exactly mean if I was capable of doing it - FumblerFingers comment

A simpler way to put it is

> I would do something **if I had the capability to do so**

or in even more simpler terms

> I would do something if I **could**

If you want to put it in the perspective if you were **capable** of doing something ^

Comment: The simplest way of covering the "capable" (as opposed to "responsible") sense is just *I **would** if I **could**.*

Comment: tysm @FumbleFingers! its a lot simpler now!

Comment: See [Why is it "If I were you" and not "If I was you"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/why-is-it-if-i-were-you-and-not-if-i-was-you) Strictly speaking we should all use "subjunctive" *If I **were** you...* in such contexts. But increasing numbers of native speakers don't bother, especially in casual conversational contexts, where *If I **was** you [I'd say it like this]* is "unexceptional" to all but the most extreme pedants.