# As if she wasn't/As if she weren't

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, irrealis-mood

In the phrase below:

> No one pays her any attention. They don’t even look at her direction, as if she **weren’t** there.

Is 'weren't' correct or should I change it to 'wasn't'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it "If I were you" and not "If I was you"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/why-is-it-if-i-were-you-and-not-if-i-was-you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Weren’t* is correct as is. Colloquially, many speakers would say *wasn’t*, but [prescriptivists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) object to that usage. The traditional grammatical analysis is that when discussing a statement contrary to fact (here, “She was not there”) one must use the subjunctive (so *was* becomes *were*).

One can sometimes contrast the indicative and the subjunctive. For instance, *If I **was** there* is a straight conditional; it might be followed by something like “…I have lost all recollection of it.” By contrast, *If I **were** there* introduces an irrealis; it makes sense when followed by things like “…I would not have to guess what’s going on.”

Comment: Excellent example to *contrast the indicative and the subjunctive*.